# Attribute based validation in ASP.NET Web Forms using MVC libraries?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, modelbinders

Is there a way in ASP.NET Webforms to accommodate attribute based validation. If so any urls where this has been demonstrated. I am not looking for open source projects.
Just as you can use MVC Routing in Web Forms, can the validation framework be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Routing is common for whole asp.net, therefore - you can easily use it [in webforms too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202.aspx).

---

'Attribute based validation' is based on so called [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx). They aren't even asp.net specific, but common for whole .net. Mvc framework just uses them etc.

You might find [this tutorial](http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/08/aspnet-webforms-validation-with-data.html) useful. I'm not sure i would use such an approach - but it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. A really good **[Validation Framework](https://imar.spaanjaars.com/477/n-layered-web-applications-with-aspnet-35-part-2-introducing-the-validation-framework)** for ASP.Net Webforms.

http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=477

[image]
<sub>(source: [spaanjaars.com](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/Images/Articles/N-Layer_Design_Next_Version/The_ContactPerson_Class_Inherits_from_ValidationBase.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Also check out the [Microsoft Enterprise Library Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203309.aspx). Compared to DataAnnotations, it has a much larger feature set, visual studio integration, more possibilities to be extended and future versions will be able to read DataAnnotations attributes, but it also has a much steeper learning curve. Because of its complexity it isn't always a good fit for small projects.